# Substitute Function German

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have used a substitute function manually all the time, which did work smoothly but was very slow. Therefore, I want to change it now to a macro but when I try to insert it to my code it doesn't work; just some of the code is within the right line in the Developer (here in stackoverflow it does work as you can see below) and the rest of the function is paste to the next lines.

This is my code:

```
Tabelle1.Range("H2:H20001").Formula.Local =
"=WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WECHSELN(
 WENN(G2=""___"";""___"";GROSS2(F2));
 ""Mr "";"""");
 ""Mrs "";"""");
 ""Dr. "";"""");
 ""Mba "";"""");
 ""Di "";"""");
 ""MSc "";"""");
 ""Msc "";"""");
 ""Kr "";"""");
 ""Gp%"";""general partner"");
 ""mbh"";""mbH"");
 ""Mbh"";""mbH"");
 ""M.B.H."";""m.b.H."");
 "" Kg"";"" KG"");
 "" Ag "";"" AG "");
 "" Og "";"" OG "");
 "" Sa "";"" SA "");  
 "" Se "";"" SE "");
 "" Ab "";"" AB "");
 "" Inc"";"" Inc."");
 "" Ltd"";"" Ltd."");
 ""D.O.O."";""d.o.o."");
 ""S.R.L."";""S.r.l."");
 ""S.Ar.l."";""SARL"");
 "" Sarl"";"" SARL"");
 ""S.P.A."";""S.p.A."");
 "" Spa"";"" S.p.A."");
 ""S.p.A.r"";""Spar"");
 ""'S"";""'s"");
 ""Self Owned"";""Self-Owned"");
 ""Oesterreich"";""Österreich"");
 ""Oö"";""OÖ""); 
 ""Nö"";""NÖ"");
 ""Aws"";""AWS"");
 ""Foerderung"";""Förderung"");
 ""Mit "";""mit "");
 ""Beschränkt"";""beschränkt"");
 "" Innovative"";"" innovative"");
 ""Und "";""und "");
 ""Von "";""von "");
 ""Für "";""für "");
 ""Zur "";""zur "");
 ""Der "";""der "");
 ""Des "";""des "");
 ""Das "";""das "");
 ""U. "";""u. "");
 ""Buergerlich"";""bürgerlich"");
 ""Bürgerlich"";""bürgerlich"");
 "".At"";"".at"");
 "".De"";"".de"");
 "".Ch"";"".ch"");
 "".Se"";"".se"");
 ""Ii"";""II"");
 ""Iii"";""III"");
 "" Llp"";"" LLP"");
 "" Fp Lp"";"" FP LP"");
 "" Bl.P"";"" BL.P."")"
```

Does someone know how can I make this one work? I also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/36384529/9456216 this solution for a similar issue (I don't have more 64 nest) but have not figured out how to apply it to my case.

Comment: Can you not either vlookup against a lookup table or use a loop over an array containing the find and replace and do the find and replace against the cells in column H?

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of substitution. If you are making this a macro-enabled workbook, I would suggest creating a UDF that cycles through 2 arrays (before / after) substituting each entry. You could even have the UDF take the array's as an input that you manage in the Name Manager

Comment: The code in the link looks like it's just doing a one to one replacement while you have varying length strings, so pretty sure it won't work for your requirements.

Comment: @HPM  I'm going to go out on a limb here:  *do **all** of the parts you need to remove hapeen to be **the last word&& of the cell's value?*  If so, there is a *much* better way to do this.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook That's exactly what I think too. But I'm totally open for another option.

Comment: @HPM ...if you were to share a sample of the data you're trying to "fix", we could likely help you with a more efficient alternative that will prevent you having to adjust your code every time you get new data.

Comment: @ashleedawg unfortunately those are different parts/words of the cell's value

Comment: That's a shame - was thinking if it was a whole cell value you could create a collection of replacement values with the key value as the value to be replaced... `colReplacements.Add "general partner", "Gp%"` and `ReplaceValue = colReplacements(Target.Value)`

Comment: @HPM **Another thing to note**:  programmatically inserting a worksheet function into a worksheet isn't going to increase speed compared to using the formula on the worksheet.  If anything, it will take longer.  Also what do you mean '`some of the code is within the right line in the Developer`"?

Comment: @ashleedawg 1. I totally see your point, but the problem is that this function was setup by someone else, who I can't contact. 2. When I paste the original function into the developer: ` Tabelle1.Range("H2:H20001").Formula.Local ="" ` it does paste a part of the code between "" but the rest just in the line below. Can you follow?

Comment: ***I figured out what's going on.*** This function isn't your *actual* problem; instead what was posted is instead **an attempted solution to your actual problem**.  The actual problem was not included in the question, likely because, (as stated by OP) it was created by someone else. **(See [xʏ ᴘʀᴏʙʟᴇᴍ](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).)**  If you would like a solution to your issue, you'll definitely need to [edit] your question to include an example of your data and a little background about what you're trying to accomplish overall. Otherise this question may as well be closed.

Comment: @ashleedawg you are wrong. Because I have to work with this formula, and as stated in the question. I do have executed it manually all the time but now I want to automate it as I did it with every other function in the workbook but for this one my solution approach does not workout and that is why I'm looking for another solution. As stated in the question I have found a similiar case but I am/was not sure if I could use it for my problem. Therefore, I was looking for support.

Comment: @HPM - I understand that this method worked before as a worksheet function. That's not what I'm saying.  I'm asking what happens in your project *before* this function - because I'm betting there's a previous step that has an issue that *this* step is "dealing with". **Also**, when replacing a worksheet function with VBA, the best solution is rarely `Range` =  `Formula`. I'm offering to find your solution, but it's impossble to code *anything* without knowing what kind of data the code is for. Is there a reason you can't post it, or an imaginary equivalent? (company & person names, I assume?)

Answer (score 2):

This is the first step with VBA ([see how to build custom functions in VBA here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20build%20custom%20formula%20with%20vba)):

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ReplacingForFun(rangeToReplace As Range) As String

    Dim changeFrom      As Variant
    Dim changeTo        As Variant
    Dim returnString    As String

    Application.Volatile

    returnString = rangeToReplace.Value2
    changeFrom = Array("Mr", "Gp%")
    changeTo = Array("", "general partner")

    Dim cnt

    For cnt = LBound(changeFrom) To UBound(changeTo)
        returnString = Replace(returnString, changeFrom(cnt), changeTo(cnt))
    Next cnt

    ReplacingForFun = returnString

End Function
```

As you see, you are defining two Arrays, `changeFrom` and `changeTo`. Each position of the array says correspondingly what should be changed to what. Thus `Mr` would be changed to `""` and `Gp%` to `general partner`.

It works like this:

[image]

As a second step, if you want to follow some best practices, it would be a good idea to define the `Arrays` in specific ranges, thus it would be easier to maintain.