# Conditional-based SUBSTITUTE function usage

Tags: excel, vba

I have the text string with various space length between the characters[image] like you can see in the image below:

I would like keep only 1 character spaces, but I have predominantly 3 and 4-character spaces. I wish I could remove them by Substitute function obe by one, although I have to know roughly what certain amount of spaces falls in my string.

I've prepared the code like this:

```
  Sub Insertcomma()
  Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
  Dim wors As Worksheet
  Set wors = ActiveSheet
  Dim myString As String

  Dim lastRow As Long

  lastRow = wors.Range("A" & wors.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = wors.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

  If InStr(myString, "  ") > 0 Then
  For Each cell In rng

  cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "    ", " ")  '4-characters space to 1 character
  cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "   ", " ")' 3-characters space to 1 character
  cell = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell, "  ", " ")' 2-character space to 1 character
  Next
  End If
  End Sub
```

I found some solutions here:

[Excel nested Substitute function macro ? (more than 64 nest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372577/excel-nested-substitute-function-macro-more-than-64-nest)

where the ReplaceSpecial function was considered, although is not helpful in terms of my problem, where I need to have the condition.

It is possible to set the condition, that if any 2-characters space occurs ("  ") then remove all spaces longer than one character (" ")?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Trim` might be something to look into.

Comment: I already use the .trim function for the very first space

Comment: I don't see any use of `.Trim` in your code but it's worth mentioning that `WorksheetFunction.Trim` isn't the same as VBA's `Trim` function.

Comment: Yes, you don't see because I haven't used it yet. OK, I will check the WorksheetFunction.Trim function if it's not the same as Trim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of iteration through all cells... Try the next code please:

```
dim i as Long
For i = 1 To 4
  ActiveSheet.cells.Replace  what:="  ", replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart
Next i
```

Please, use your real sheet instead of `ActiveSheet`...

And a specific column if you want to allow to others column having more than one space...

Comment: That's perfect, although could you give me some explanation?
I need to understand:
what does the i mean?
Is it the number of spaces between the single works in my string maybe?
Why 1 to 3, whilst I considered from 2 to 4?
In the Replace I only have "  ", but I need also "   " and "    ".

Comment: Take care - this will change everywhere in the sheet - which may or may not be a desired side effect not just in your data rows. Also its remove all whitespace - I think the requirement is to leave one space

Comment: @FaneDuru The requirement is to leave a single space I think. Your logic will reduce even number of space to no spaces and odd number spaces to one space

Comment: @JohnnieL  I know, I put Replace "  ", " " instead.

Comment: Sorry I dont follow, thats replacing a single space with a single space? Apologies if I am mis-reading that ...

Comment: @MKR: I adapted/corrected the above code... It could work for the first time only if you tried replacing something searching for `XlsPart`... And I made a mistake first time. It will replace two spaces with only one... Please, use the updated code.

Comment: @Warcupine: Yes you were right! I initially had in mind replacing two spaces with one, but write ""... Then, it looks to me (wrongly) that it my work... I adapted it with some other (necessary) parameters.

Comment: @JohnnieL: Yes. I corrected my answer code. I initially thought I used " " like replacement string...

Comment: I wasnt familiar with the `LookAt` @FaneDuru - thats  useful parameter to be aware of, +1

Comment: @JohnnieL:  If you had the chance to (manually or by code) use before the 'Find and Replace' window for partial string, it should work. Otherwise it should work only for all the cell content... Thanks!

Comment: Noteworthy side effect - the dialog box remembers last settings ... "The settings for LookAt, SearchOrder, MatchCase, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time that you use this method." - API docs

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try this

```
    For Each cell In rng
        dim temp as string
        Do
            temp = cell.value
            cell.value = Replace(cell.value, Space(2), Space(1))
        Loop Until temp = cell.value
    next cell
```